# Xcode: According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: '[ ]' for the key 'keychain-access-groups'

Tags: xcode, store, keychain

I'm facing this issue uploading a new build to the store, I basically didn't change anything in the code, just added a localised string for a new language.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx1mI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, just search for the text `keychain-access-groups` and remove the Key `Key Chain Access Groups` which should be an empty array
[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tscq2.png)

Comment: Same issue here, thanks for the solution!